# I try to install Oracle 19 on CENTOS 8 GUI by run vncserver and X11

Tags: centos, x11, oracle-database

I try to install Oracle 19 on CENTOS 8-GUI by using vncserver and X11.
When I try to run this `./runInstaller`, I got this `ERROR: Unavale to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable`
After I install X11 then I run these line:
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
`xhost +`
But I got this `unable to open display ":0.0"`
I try to see /etc/ssh/sshd_config and I got `X11Forwarding yes` and  `X11UseLocalhost yes`.
I got stuck there for a day.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer, the one you use to connect to server, is a Linux or other UNIX machine with a GUI, you can install `xorg-x11-xauth` package to the server,
`sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth`,
then log in to it using,
`ssh -X IP or name`
and you should be able to run the GUI installer of Oracle. No need to export display.

If your computer is a Windows or Mac, you should start an X server first. On Windows there's a nice terminal emulator, [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) which starts an X server automatically.

Comment: I heart about some packages call Preinstallation Oracle 19. Is that work on Centos 8?

Comment: Perhaps yes, but you have to locate the rpm and install it on Centos 8. You can also use Oracle Linux (almost identical to Centos) which includes the pre-installation package for Oracle RDBMS. Yet the problem you have is not related to Oracle DB pre-req. There's also another option for installing Oracle DB: Download the rpm instead of zip. Much easier, but you don't control paths etc during installation.